# What must I return in a GraphQL Mutation with Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to implement a GraphQL server that uses Sequelize in the back-end (to work with MSSQL behind the scenes).
And I have a query that works perfectly (retrieving data from a single SQL table) as expected.

But then I set up a mutation for the same schema, and when I run the mutation in GraphiQL I find that, while it does execute the stuff inside the mutation's resolve function (which is to create an instance of my Sequelize schema), it does not return my object back to me.

[image]

Now, I figure it's because my Sequelize `.create` function returns a promise and resolve can't handle that?

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
resolve(_,args){
  Forecast.create({
    bunit: args.bunit,
    season: args.season,
    position: args.position,
    currency: args.currency,
    settle_date: new Date(args.settle_date),
    reference: args.reference
  }).then(forecast => {
    return forecast;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    return err;
  });
}
```

I can't find any clear explanation or tutorial that shows me how to construct what the resolve function needs to return when I'm doing something asynchronously. Or I just don't understand it, which is also quite likely.

Comment: you should `return` like this: `return Forecast.create(...`

Comment: I did that at first, but it wouldn't work. However, I just removed the `.then` and `.catch` calls as well, effectively leaving the handling of the returning promise to the resolve function, and that seems to work!

Comment: I do wonder though, what that means for error handling etc. Will my mutation automatically return the rejection of the promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adam's suggestion above worked in this instance.
I am surprised we don't need to read the promise the `.create` method calls, but it seems to work just fine that way.

```js
resolve(_,args){
      return Forecast.create({
        bunit: args.bunit,
        season: args.season,
        position: args.position,
        currency: args.currency,
        settle_date: new Date(args.settle_date),
        reference: args.reference
      });
      // .then(forecast => {
      //   console.error(err);
      //   //return forecast;
      // }).catch(err => {
      //   console.error(err);
      //   //return err;
      // });

      //return newForecast;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: this way you are able to see the errors from sequelize?

Comment: @stackdave Yes, graphql will add an "errors" property to its response (same as "data"), if the promise from your resolver (in this case Sequelize's .create function) is rejected for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `then` and `catch` implementation works but shouldn't be done, you've encountered a promises `then`-chain.
Each `then` (or catch) `return` section changes the returned value of the resolver.

Hence, adding a `return` on the `Forecast` AND returns within the `then` and the `catch` is the right approach

```
resolve(_,args){
      return Forecast.create({
        bunit: args.bunit,
        season: args.season,
        position: args.position,
        currency: args.currency,
        settle_date: new Date(args.settle_date),
        reference: args.reference
      });
       .then(forecast => {
         console.error(err);
         return forecast;
       }).catch(err => {
         console.error(err);
         return err;
       });

      return newForecast;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is definitely not going to work: a) because you forgot to remove a semi-colon before the .then() call, and b) because you're returning "newForecast" at the end which does not exist.  None of this is necessary, just return the Promise that Forecast.create() returns, as above.